# Unable to create polyline for map in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Essentially I would like to create a polyline that connects all coordinates together with a dashed line. How can this be done with the following setup in SwiftUI.

The following is how I am currently drawing the MapMarkers on the map, can a polyline be used to connect them?

```
@State var myAddresses = [Locations]()

struct Place: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}

Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, annotationItems: myAddresses) { place in
    MapMarker(coordinate: place.coordinate)
}
                
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20, height: 500)
.cornerRadius(10)
```

Comment: You can’t you have to interface with MKMapView

Comment: Can you please show how this can be done?